# Is there really such a thing as the onion architecture?

Tags: design, dependency-inversion, onion-architecture

Note: BLL = Business Logic Layer (can also mean your domain)

I'm trying to understand the onion architecture. It seems to me that it's actually the same thing as the layered architecture, only with the dependency inversion principle (DIP) applied. For example, this is the typical layered architecture (arrows represent dependencies):

UI > BLL > DAL

Note: That's simplified, and should not imply that DIP can't/isn't used with it. DIP simply means that we should depend on abstractions.

This is the typical onion flow (also simplified):

UI > BLL < DAL

Notice the last arrow is reversed. The BLL has the abstractions, so they're at the center of the onion, and the other layers reference it.
Onion article: http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/

Since I'm used to the layered architecture, I wanted to see what the flow would look like if I combined that with DIP. Here it is:

UI > [interface] < BLL > [interface] < DAL

Excellent diagram of DIP, which mirrors this.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle

Here is an article explaining the difference between layered and onion. It made me have the questions I presented above.
http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/12/03/layers-onions-ports-adapters-its-all-the-same/

So my question is, what is the difference between the onion architecture, and the layered architecture with DIP? Is there one?

My question has been flagged as a possible duplicate of this one:
[Onion architecture vs 3 layered architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/319747/29526)
Mine is different because I want to know if there really is such a thing as the onion architecture. If you claim the onion architecture is layered + DIP, then does the onion really exist? Or would that mean that the onion really is just a *version* of layered, like layered with bad practices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Onion architecture vs 3 layered architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/319747/onion-architecture-vs-3-layered-architecture)

Comment: I'm looking for a good conversation about this issue. Why not give the post a chance instead of closing it within minutes of asking? Let's see what happens. It's a serious attempt at trying to understand.

Comment: Words mean what people think they mean.  If people use 'onion architecture' to mean something specific that exists, then the 'onion architecture' exists.  I think what you are really asking is whether it is synonymous to the Layered Architecture w/ DIP.

Comment: consider giving a read to guidance here:  [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)

Comment: @JimmyJames Yes, that's what I'm asking. And if it's true, then I wish articles that explain the onion architecture would state that right up front. Instead there are these long explanations, and diagrams, that explain the onion architecture as if it's some radical new concept.

Comment: I think the real question should be "What is difference between layered architecture and layered architecture with DIP?" . And to me, that difference is huge and critical to what onion architecture really is about.

Comment: Also take a look at the [hexagon pattern](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems to me that most 'new' things in software architecture are old ideas refurbished and combined with new technologies or other ideas.  Often these are incremental.

In this case, the change that I think matters is the database is no longer the center of the design.  This is not an minor change; it's pretty fundamental.  So is the "onion architecture" really just the layered architecture plus DIP?  Maybe.  But steel is roughly iron plus carbon.  Does that mean steel isn't a real thing?

Words are labels.  This one stuck.  I'm not sure what else there is to say about it.

Comment: "the database is no longer the center of the design." That implies that it was in the layered architecture. Why would that be the case? Because everything depends on it? (The arrows all point toward it.)

Comment: @BobHorn, Correct.  In multi-tiered architecture with the database as the bottom tier, you typically end up with leaky abstractions or a lot of business code in stored procedures.  In the Onion architecture, the persistence is mapped to domain objects and all the business logic is in those domain objects.  It makes the database a bolt-on, and much easier to trade it for NoSQL if that fits the architecture needed.  Or more likely the case when the licensing for one database becomes too expensive it makes it easier to change for another database from another vendor.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch: It doesn't have to be that way.  You can have a layered architecture and simply avoid stored procedures.  And decoupling the database from an architecture is an unremarkable technique; if that's all there is to onion architecture it's not particularly interesting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure I would call it 'remarkable' but the onion architecture forbids using the database (or any other storage infrastructure) directly.  I've seen a lot of layered architectures where some people would go through the service layer but other teams might go directly to the database.  As I understand it, if you say "onion architecture" you are specifically saying that it not an option.

Comment: "If I have seen so far it is only because I have stood on the shoulders of giants" Isaac Newton. There are few things that aren't really some other thing, just with something else added or removed. What the op is really complaining about is the hype used to get us to listen to the lesson. If you come away saying "I knew that already" then great. But not everyone knew that. I'm happy if we can keep down the number of names for identical things. Layered is not the same as onion but ports & adapters as well as clean architecture sure seem the same to me.

Comment: I'm not complaining about the hype. What bothers me is the explanations that make it difficult to understand. I had to dig and dig to find out it was just layered + DIP. Say that up front, you know? I've been doing layered + DIP for years, so I've already been doing the Onion architecture.

Comment: @BobHorn try writing stuff like this some time. You'll find the biggest problem is knowing your audience. Knowing what you can assume they understand and what they don't.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I agree it doesn't _have_ to be that way, but the majority of mid-life apps I've inherited using that architecture _are_ that way.

Comment: @BobHorn "Layered architecture plus the dependency inversion principle" is a bit of a mouthful.  It's a lot easier to say "Onion architecture".  Additionally, I would argue that "Layered + DIP" isn't much more illuminating than "onion".  Someone could have a layered architecture that uses a DI container and think that's layered + DIP.  Sometimes it's an advantage to create a new term.  A good example of how this goes wrong 'service orientation'  it has a specific meaning but the generic nature of the term 'service' made it easy to hijack as a new label on old wine.

Comment: @CandiedOrange For my 2 cents, 'Ports and Adapters' is far to generic.  'Hexagon architecture' seems detached from any real meaning.  'Clean architecture': well, that could mean anything.  But as anyone who's seen *Shrek* knows, onions have layers.  That puts an image in your head that is isomorphic to what it's describing.

Comment: @JimmyJames what you're asking for is a name that evokes a good metaphor. That's fine but what I was complaining about in my earlier comment is that some people won't contribute to an idea without giving it a new name that will drive people to their blog. We have a distressing number of synonyms in this field and I suspect this is why.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I had actually read your comment not as a complaint but just as a casual observation.  I don't disagree and my point is more that, if we want to choose a single term, 'onion' is the best of the options presented, in my opinion.

Comment: @JimmyJames with that I agree. So I'll stop complaining. ;)